# Magento 2 Search Nightmare

Tags: magento2

If one goes by the traditional Magento methodology to repeat a class in layout files, then the following should work:

Magento Example in Catalog:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml"/>
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
```

So I want to create a new file in Catalog Search

```
<block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" name="search.result" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::result.phtml" cacheable="false">
<!-- ^ Magento default -->
<block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" name="search.count" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::count.phtml" cacheable="false">
```

That will yield a glorious:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getLoadedProductCollection() on boolean. Why?!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you are replacing result.phtml by count.phtml?

Comment: No, I am adding count.phtml to display the number of search results. Notice how in the Catalog XML, the subsequent call does not replace the former call(s).

Answer (score 0):

Magento make objects boolean(false) if class can't be found. Problem with Block object, not with *.phtml file

Comment: But the class is applied for search.result. It does exist, it's just not designed to be replicated. I don't quite get what that missing element is.